# Starting position in rule of product problem-solving

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the following basic question:

> With the numbers $0,1,2,3,4,5$, how many odd 3-digit numbers can we
> write without repeating any of the numbers.

Albeit we can start from any position, starting from the left side will force us to branch our choices and use rule of sum to find the final answer. But starting from the right and then going left enables us to calculate the solution by merely doing $4\times4\times3$.

Now my question is that whether there is a concise way to find that "optimal path" in similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use commonsense.

In fact, to avoid branching for this particular problem, choosing from right to left won't eliminate branching,

you need to choose in the sequence $last\, digit,\,first\, digit\, and \,middle\, digit$,

thus writing in chosen order, $3\times4\times4$

Comment: Yes I have mentioned going right (last digit) and then left (first digit) which means considering the middle digit last. Maybe bad wording. So there seems to be no particular way.

Comment: Oh, the wording wasn't clear to me. In any case, idk of any general rule for the question you have posed. Of course, $0$ at the beginning obviously means you can't start from the first digit, but when it is combined with other restrictions, you have to think it out. And you can't avoid branching in *all* problems.